# python compiler book

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I want to know that if there exists any book that describes about python compiler ?
There is a book on ruby MRI in Japanese which has been translated into English. I wonder there is such book exists for python.

Sorry, if this is already asked.

Comment: What Python compiler? Do you just mean the bytecode generator or something that creates true executables?

Comment: Actually, thinking about *a compiler* as about something that creates executables is too narow. There is a source code at the beginning and it must be transformed to something else. Whether into more abstract code or native machine code is not that different.

Answer (score 3):

If you're just talking about the CPython bytecode generator (rather then a *true* compiler making native executable code or any of the non-CPython implementations), the first port of call would be the [Design of CPython’s Compiler](http://docs.python.org/devguide/compiler.html) page.

It's part of the [Python Developer's Guide](http://docs.python.org/devguide/index.html).